# GNU Radio programming pattern / control flow graph

Tags: c#, user-interface, design-patterns, gnuradio, control-flow-graph

I’m about to start developing an application (probably in C#) that has similar mechanics to GNU radio but a totally different purpose.

GNU Radio has a GUI that is like your typical flowchart type editor / drawing tool, but each object displayed on the “canvas” is part of a reactive control flow graph (rather than a flowchart box).

Basically, they are black boxes each having a specific internal purpose and each also having input(s) and output(s) where required.

For the simplicity of explanation let’s say my scope is to create a GUI canvas that I can drag objects on to and a run / stop button (to run the “program”). I suppose in some ways a little like the GUI from programming Scratch the kids programming tool.

I initially have 3 objects.

1)  Some type of keyboard input box where I will input some Base64 encoded text. This has only an output that goes into object number 2.

2)  This object takes input fed to it (the above encoded text) and converts it back to UTF-8 (its only purpose) and outputs it to the object number 3.

3)  This object takes the input fed to it (from object number 3) and outputs it to screen (in its little box).

What these objects do is not important this is simply for example. This is basically how GNU Radio works except its passing digital signal data around rather than text.

My question is what sort of programming patterns does GNU radio use (before I pull it apart) or what sort of OOP type patterns or ideas should I maybe by looking at for this type of application. Or even some good Google links.

I have tried for a few hours now trying to Google something but it’s really difficult to find the right words that don’t return x zillion adverts for flowchart software for sale and such like.

I should also add that new objects (black boxes) can be added later.

Answer (score 1):

GNU Radio is written in C++; what you perceive as "black" boxes can actually either be signal processing *blocks* or hierarchical blocks, which themselves contain a flow graph.

The base concept is that every block type is a class that inherits from a "mother" class and overloads a `work` method, which gets called when there's new input data (and enough free space in the output buffer). Each block runs in its own thread, so that GNU Radio inherently pipelines within multithreading environment, often achieving full parallelism (meaning that all CPU cores are working in parallel on different blocks). This greatly improves throughput compared to single-threaded signal processing systems.

For a quick and superficial intro, read the introductory chapter of the official GNU Radio Tutorials [*A modular, flowgraph based Approach to Digital Signal Processing](https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php/Guided_Tutorial_Introduction#A_modular.2C_flowgraph_based_Approach_to_Digital_Signal_Processing).

If you want to know more about the way GNU Radio works with (seemingly) circular buffers to exchange data between blocks, see [my blog post on that topic](https://www.gnuradio.org/blog/buffers/).

Generally, the application you're building is very dissimilar to GNU Radio; so I'd argue, a simpler, single-threaded model is much more what you want.

Aside from that, you could probably even avoid writing any marshalling code yourself and just write tiny C# programs that take input via stdin and generate output on stdout, and just pipe `|` them (very classical Unix way of doing text processing).

Comment: Thats a good start thank you. To be honest the application is far more complicated than I have described its just not signal processing. Its more roughly speaking processing streams of data though i know thats not very descriptive. It probably will need multiple threads and each black box will contain flow graphs themselves. Thats why I like how GNU radio works. I have chosen c# as Im experimenting with a cross platform GUI called avalonia as I do really want a good cross platform GUI (ha ha we only wish) and I dont want to use QT or Java.

Comment: Urgent advice: mentally separate processing from visuals. Your choice of GUI toolkit should have no influence on your signal processing design! Also, if your application is very different, your example in your question is a bad one. Better describe what you actually want to build. Chances are that someone else already did that.

Comment: Yes I completely agree and it was my intention. Though it will have a 2D implementation initially my end goal is to be able to visualise this in VR (or whatever). So Im totally with you on that. Its really why Im trying to get an Idea of other peoples issues and ideas of the design.

Comment: Stop even thinking about visualization while designing a signal processing architecture! Orthogonal problems.